# Два разных запороса - один ответ, в чем ошибка?

Tags: php

При запросе `act=new_user&username=qwerty` выдает `Файл не найден`, хотя должен создавать директорию или выдать ошибку:

```
<?php

$act = $_GET['act'];
$command = $_GET['command'];
$parameter = $_GET['value'];
$username = $_GET['username']; ;

if ($act=="setup_server"){
if ( !file_exists( "users.txt" ) ){
touch( "users.txt" );
echo "Сервер установлен";
exit;
}
else{
echo "Сервер установлен";
exit;
}
}

if (($act=="get_users") && (file_exists( "users.txt" ))){
$f_users = fopen( "users.txt", "r" ) or die ( "Не удалось открыть файл" );
$first=true;
while ( !feof ( $f_users ) ){
if ($first==true){
$all_users=( fgets( $f_users , 1024 ) )."|";
$first=false;
} else {
$all_users .= ( fgets( $f_users , 1024 ) )."|";
}
} 
echo $all_users;
exit;
} else {
echo "Файл не найден";
exit;
}

if ($act=="new_user"){
mkdir ($username, 0777 ) or die('Ошибка добавления') ;
exit;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное надо этот кусок

```
...
else {//перенести после проверки на "new_user"
echo "Файл не найден";
exit;
}
//добавить else if
if ($act=="new_user"){
mkdir ($username, 0777 ) or die('Ошибка добавления') ;
exit;
}
...
```

Надо переделать на предмет того чтобы else был совсем после? 
В Вашем случае вы проверяете на get_users и если не оно - то пишете что файл не найден. до проверки на "new_user" даже не доходит

P.S.

Форматируйте код в программах по любому удобному Вам стандарту. Это дисциплинирует, и позволяет лучше читать код.